# index.html stored in css/ directory

Tags: directory

I am building a site that has a page titled 'CSS'. So, to me, the most logical place to store the page's index.html file is in the corresponding css/ folder.

Are there any potential problems I could run into using the css/ directory as a subpage folder as well as the place I store my css/sass like i the following directory:

```
siteroot
css/
  index.html (sub-page I am asking about)
  mainstyle.css
  sass/
index.html
js/
  app.js
img/
  example.png
```

It's worth pointing out I'm not using relative URLs, so I can't see file paths being an issue.

Comment: Couldn't you just name place your page in your root folder and name it `css.html`? Having HTML pages in assets folders is usually considered bad practice. If you only care about how the URL reads, you should look into .htaccess and `RewriteRules`

Comment: Thanks @Marc-AntoineParent, I've since added all my `.html` pages into an `/includes/` folder and created a `Rewrite Rule` so that `/includes/css.html` points to `/css/`.